# Android "New Game Button" TicTacToe Game

Tags: java, android, button

I'm trying to put a Start New Game (Joc nou) button, but when I press this button, it is not working as it should. Usually, it starts a new game but it also puts an 'X' on the first position of the table (mBoardsButtons[0])

```
      package xsi0.cristi.ro;

      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.app.Activity;
      import android.graphics.Color;
      //import android.view.Menu;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.widget.Button;
      import android.widget.TextView;
      //import android.view.*;
      public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private XSI0 mGame;

private Button[] mBoardsButtons;
private Button  jocnou;

private TextView mInfoTextView;
private TextView mHumanCount;
private TextView mTieCount;
private TextView mAndroidCount;

private int mHumanCounter=0;
private int mTieCounter=0;
private int mAndroidCounter=0;

private boolean mHumanFirst=true;
private boolean mGameOver=false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mGame=new XSI0();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //cod nou
    jocnou=new Button(this);
    //cod nou
            jocnou =(Button)findViewById(R.id.JocNew);

    mBoardsButtons = new Button[mGame.getMarimeTabla()];
    mBoardsButtons[0]= (Button)findViewById(R.id.unu);
    mBoardsButtons[1]= (Button)findViewById(R.id.doi);
    mBoardsButtons[2]= (Button)findViewById(R.id.trei);
    mBoardsButtons[3]= (Button)findViewById(R.id.patru);
    mBoardsButtons[4]= (Button)findViewById(R.id.cinci);
    mBoardsButtons[5]= (Button)findViewById(R.id.sase);
    mBoardsButtons[6]= (Button)findViewById(R.id.sapte);
    mBoardsButtons[7]= (Button)findViewById(R.id.opt);
    mBoardsButtons[8]= (Button)findViewById(R.id.noua);

    mInfoTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Info);
    mHumanCount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.uwins);
    mTieCount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Drawscount);
    mAndroidCount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.defeatscount);

    mHumanCount.setText(Integer.toString(mHumanCounter));
    mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
    mAndroidCount.setText(Integer.toString(mAndroidCounter));

    //mGame=new XSI0();
    jocnou.setText("Joc nou");
    jocnou.setEnabled(true);
    jocnou.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener());

    incepeJocNou();
}

private void incepeJocNou(){
    //mGameOver=false;
    mGame.curataTabla();

    for(int i=0;i<mBoardsButtons.length;i++){
        mBoardsButtons[i].setText("");
        mBoardsButtons[i].setEnabled(true);
        mBoardsButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener(i));
    }

    /*//codnou

    jocnou.setText("Joc nou");
    jocnou.setEnabled(true);
    jocnou.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener());
    */

    if(mHumanFirst){
        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.Utilizatorul_primul);
        mHumanFirst=false;
    }
    else{
        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.mutare_android);
        int move=mGame.getMiscareComputer();
        setMove(mGame.Android,move);
        mHumanFirst=true;
    }
}

private class ButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{
    int location;

    public ButtonClickListener(int location){
        this.location=location;
        }
    //cod nou
    public ButtonClickListener(){

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        //cod nou
        if(jocnou.isPressed()){

            mGameOver=true;

            incepeJocNou();
            //mBoardsButtons[0].setText("");

            mGameOver=false;
            }

        if(!mGameOver){
            if(mBoardsButtons[location].isEnabled()){
                setMove(mGame.User,location);

                int winner=mGame.verificaCastigator();

                if(winner==0)
                {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.mutare_android);
                    int move=mGame.getMiscareComputer();
                    setMove(mGame.Android,move);
                    winner=mGame.verificaCastigator();
                }

                if(winner==0)
                    mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.mutare_utilizator);
                else if(winner==1){
                    mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.rezultat_egal);
                    mTieCounter++;
                    //mTieCounter.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));

                    mGameOver=true;
                }
                else if(winner==2){
                    mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.utilizator_castiga);
                    mHumanCounter++;
                    //mHumanCounter.setText(Integer.toString(mHumanCounter));
                    mGameOver=true;
                }

                else{
                    mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.android_castiga);
                    mAndroidCounter++;
                    //mAndroidCounter.setText(Integer.toString(mAndroidCounter));
                    mGameOver=true;
            }
        }

    }
}

/*public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}*/

    }
private void setMove(char player,int location){
    mGame.setMiscare(player, location);

    mBoardsButtons[location].setEnabled(false);
    mBoardsButtons[location].setText(String.valueOf(player));
    if(player==mGame.User){
        mBoardsButtons[location].setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
        else
            mBoardsButtons[location].setTextColor(Color.RED);

}
}
```

Comment: That's pretty cool. Nice code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1)  What does curataTabla() do?  I don't see this method - it's possible you have a bug in this code which causes the position to remain set.

2)  Are you sure Human first is selected?  It's also possible that the computer is always going first, and just happens to be choosing this location every time.

Hard to debug without more code.

Also, check this code:

```
 //cod nou
    if(jocnou.isPressed()){

        mGameOver=true;

        incepeJocNou();
        //mBoardsButtons[0].setText("");

        mGameOver=false;
        }

    if(!mGameOver){
```

Everytime new game is selected, you set mGameover to true, create a new game, then set it to false.  That means that everytime you do a new Game, you're actually doing a new game AND a move, not just a new game.  I'm not sure this is where the bug comes from, but it could be leading to unexpected behavior.

I think you should try breaking the New Game onClickListener and normal ClickListernes into two separate listeners and see if that resolves this.  My guess is that you're getting unintended behavior because you're dual purposing one listener.

Comment: 1) curataTabla just cleen the table:public void curataTabla(){
  for(int i=0;i<MarimeTabla;i++)
  {
   Tabla[i]=SpatiuGol;
  }
 }

Comment: 2)If computer is first selected,it puts a '0', then 'X' and again '0'.Human always plays with 'x' and computer with '0'.So,if I press the "new game" button it appers a 'x' without the user doing something

Comment: See edits... I think you might try breaking the newGame clickListener out since it's behavior has nothing to do with the bother buttons on clickListeners.

Comment: Fixed it:if(jocnou.isPressed()){
   
   
   
    //mGameOver=true;
    
    mGameOver=false;
    incepeJocNou();
    mGame.curataTabla();
    //mBoardsButtons[0].setText("");
    
    
    }

Comment: Great, not sure if my answer helped or not, if it did please accept =)